# Back Button doesn't fire useEffect with location as dependency

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

On pressing back button of browser the `useEffect` doesn't fire although the location is being changed. Redirecting url using window.open() doesn't fire a change in this useEffect once I press back button and return to page from where I was redirected.

```js
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  // something that needs to run when there is a change in url

}, [location.pathname])

window.open(someUrl,"_self");
```

Things happening after window.open

1. I am using SAML method to authenticate hence it redirects to a 3rd party server on logout
2. Multiple redirects happen once 3rd party receives the logout request
3. Once the logout is successful, I am redirected to my site from the server.

Comment: Set the dependency to just location.

Comment: What *specific* issue do you need help with? The back navigation and `useEffect` hook, or something with the `window.open`? The initial question regarding the `useEffect` hook and location has been answered. Anything else after that is likely unrelated and off-topic for the post. You can create a new SO post for other issues like using `window.open`. Or is this all just an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) post where you have an issue with some external redirects you think the `useEffect` hook in the post will resolve, but you are asking for help with that instead of the root issue?

Answer (score 3):

The `useLocation` hook returns a `Location` object with the following interface ([source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/d5fa8fb730cf8859903cf4d049e66901a83fb7ce/packages/router/history.ts#L35C5-L69)):

```js
export interface Path {
  pathname: string;
  search: string;
  hash: string;
}

export interface Location extends Path {
  state: any;
  key: string;
}
```

There is no `path` property. The `useEffect` hook should use `location.pathname` as the dependency.

```
const location = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  // something that needs to run when there is a change in url path
}, [location.pathname]);
```

or

```
const { pathname } = useLocation();

useEffect(() => {
  // something that needs to run when there is a change in url path
}, [pathname]);
```

### Demo

[image: Edit back-button-doesnt-fire-useeffect-with-location-as-dependency]

Comment: Sorry, I had already used location.pathname and made a typo in my question. I have updated my question now.

Comment: @BijanKundu Do you want the effect to run on *any* location change, or only on back navigations? Can you edit the post to show where the effect is used?

Comment: @BijanKundu FWIW here's a running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/back-button-doesnt-fire-useeffect-with-location-as-dependency-mlokvo?file=/src/App.js) demo with the effect running when the back button is clicked.

Comment: updated the question to add more details. This particular issue is happening when I am using window.Open()

Comment: @BijanKundu What does `window.open` have to do with the `useEffect` hook and associated callback function? Is there some extracurricular issue with calling `window.open` completely separate from any issue with running an effect when the location changes?